# Android emulator stability issues

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

While starting emulator (via Android studio AVD Manager), I am getting this error:

> GPU Driver Issue
>
> Your GPU driver information:
>
> GPU #1
>     Make: 8086
>     Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
>     Device ID: 0166
>
> Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.  As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer.  Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.
>
> OK

I tried two options to resolve but no luck.

1. I verified driver status of my laptop (Lenovo P500) [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html) and got a message that the driver is up to date.
2. When creating a new Emulator, I tried setting it to use system driver explicitly.

Could anyone please advise what I need to do?

Comment: same issue in MacOS High Sierra MBP Mid 2012 model

Comment: Any luck solving this? I have MBP Mid 2012 with this problem as well